# SQL Server 2012: Change order of COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql-server

I have this cursor:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
     SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
     WHERE TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@TableName, 'form.', '')

OPEN cur    
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @fieldname
```

Can I change the order of the cursor?

Something like this:

I get now:

```
@fieldname = field1
@fieldname = field2
@fieldname = field3
```

But I want to get them with this order:

```
@fieldname = field2
@fieldname = field1
@fieldname = field3
```

Ultimately what I want to achieve is use the order that field names have in another table (with these columns among others : `fieldname` and `fieldorder`) . So I want to use `fieldorder` field to specify the order in the cursor iteration.

**EDIT** I tried that with no luck:

```
SELECT 
    QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS inf 
JOIN
    dbo.FormFields AS tf ON COLUMN_NAME = tf.fieldname 
WHERE   
    TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(@TableName, 'form.', '') 
    AND SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0') 
ORDER BY
    tf.fieldorder
```

Comment: Just add an `order by` to your query

Comment: fieldorder is in another table not in `@TableName`

Comment: Than join that other table.

Comment: @HoneyBadger check my edited post

Comment: "with no luck" is not a problem description. **Why** didn't it work? Also, why do you need the substring?

Comment: @HoneyBadger it doesnt return anything

Comment: Is the join condition correct (are the column_name and fieldname exactly the same)? Do you have columns starting with 0-9? (In your example the column names *end* in a numeric).

Comment: @HoneyBadger thank you. I had to use QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)